# How to close Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want a javascript code for closing the whole Firefox not just a Tab. Could anyone has experience with this? I have tried the methods that I have found over Google but I can not solve this problem

Comment: Why would you need that? Any user will be upset when your page closes his/her entire browser with all tabs.

Comment: why do you wan't to do that, is it from an extention?

Comment: are you trying to do this in a web page or with a Firefox plugin?

Comment: I hope this isn't possible. If I navigate to some website, I would not appreciate it if the browser is shut down suddenly.

Comment: Why? Well, suppose the client JS somehow discovered that the user was bogus; or had hacked his way onto the site. One way to do the right thing is to shut down the browser.

Comment: Why not format all his drives? ;)

Comment: What is more, can you think of hacker who hack his way onto the site and is stopped by stupid CLIENT SIDE JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know anything about hacking. I'm just curious. Do hackers use web browsers to hack sites? I don't think so...

Comment: @Pete Wilson — No, the correct response would be for the server to start issuing 403 Forbidden responses to any HTTP request from that user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't exit the program with JavaScript.  That is a system command that JS doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 4):

A webpage will never have permission to shut down the browser entirely.

Comment: A window opened with JavaScript can be closed by JavaScript. A window opened by a user can only be closed by a user.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're trying to use Javascript in a web page to do this.

The short answer is: You can't.

The Javascript code running within a given web page will only ever know anything about it's own context -- ie the page it is running on. It will know nothing about any other tabs or browser windows, and it cannot access them.

You can tell Javascript to close the current window, because it has access to its own window, but you cannot tell it to close all windows because it doesn't have access to them.

The only exception to this where you can use JS to jump context between different windows and tabs is where one window/tab has caused another to open. In this case, the parent window should have a handle to the one that was opened, and that window should in turn be able to access it's parent using the `window.opener` object.

So, if the windows/tabs open in Firefox have *all* been opened by each other, then you *might* be able to generate a call chain which allows you to close them all. But it'll still be a tricky task, and it still definitely won't allow you to touch any windows or tabs which have been opened separately by the user.

I hope that helps.